# mass-restarting httpd on lots of EC2 instances

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a variable number of EC2 instances (CentOS 64) that contain an apache web server that caches a bunch of code in production mode.

Now every time I make some changes to the code (generally on a weekly basis) I have to log into each one of them instances and do a "su" then "service httpd restart"

Is there a way to automate this so that I can run a single command on one of the instances it would connect to all others and restart it? Getting really time consuming especially when the application has spawned some 20-30 instances on its own (happens on some days when we get high traffic)

Thanks!

Comment: If you set up your instances to have an authorized SSH key for root, then you can do `ssh root@instance service httpd restart` for each instance. It would then be a simple matter of scripting to loop over all of your instances.

Comment: If you have more things to do regularly on a lot of servers, maybe [Python Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/) scripting is something to look at. It acts as an abstraction layer on top of your shell commands, is easy to use (if you are comfortable with Python) and extremely powerful.

Comment: When I ssh (using pems) to each instance I also have to do a su and enter the root pwd, ec2-user can't restart httpd. Would prefer a solution that doesn't involve additional software, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You can give sudo privileges to ec2-user just for apache restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dancer's shell](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en), `dsh`, is provided specifically to do this. No 'scripting' required. As @tix3 suggests, you should probably also convince `sudo` on those machines (configure `/etc/sudoers` using `visudo`) to configure them to accept your restart command.

Comment: Doesn't look like it works "out of the box", I'd have to connect to each machine and either install that lib and/or set up sudo :(

Comment: No, what you need to do is have a ssh key that you push to those machines. Then you put the hosts in a group file and tell dsh to perform an operation on that group. Obviously any solution is going to need to take a list of hosts before startup. I mean, we don't expect DNS to be populated automatically.

And dsh is not a lib -- it doesn't require anything on the endpoints. It is just ssh.

Comment: Can you not just set up your AMI with sudo preconfigured? I mean, this is how ubuntu is by default on EC2.

Comment: Will probably end up doing just that. Tried avoiding it so I won't have to refactor all configurations for autoscaling and so on.